# how to have two aggregation in cypher query in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have problem with complex queries;
here is my cypher query:

```
params.put("query", "name:*");
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( "start n=node:groups({query}) 
match n<-[:Members_In]-x 
with n,count(distinct x) as numberOfUsers
where numOfUsers>avg(numOfUsers) 
return  n.name,numOfUsers ", params );
```

`n` is the group name and x is the users of each group.
how can i have avg of group users count and compare it with each group users count?
can I get the average number of group users and then return the groups with more users than avg?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get the avg and the counts in the same query, without restarting. So here's my attempt:

```
start n=node:groups({query}) 
match n<-[:Members_In]-x 
with n, count(distinct x) as cnt
with avg(cnt) as av
start n=node:groups({query}) 
match n<-[:Members_In]-x
with n, av, count(distinct x) as numOfUsers
where numOfUsers > av
return n.name, numOfUsers, av
```