# filtering a filtered a Cypher query result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi here's my current query i'd like to 're-filter':

```
START movie = node(*)
MATCH user-[:LIKE]->category-[:SIMILAR*0..3]-()<-[:TAGGED]->movie
WHERE user.name = "current_user"

WITH DISTINCT movie, user, category

RETURN user.name, category.name, ID(movie), movie.name
ORDER BY movie.name;
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/u19iim

Here's how it looks like after current query:

```
+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
| user.name    | category.name  | ID(movie) | movie.name              |
+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
| current_user | c              | 14        | movie_c_and_d_and_e     |
| current_user | d              | 14        | movie_c_and_d_and_e     |
| current_user | e              | 14        | movie_c_and_d_and_e     |
| current_user | a              | 9         | movie_of_a_and_b_and_b1 |
| current_user | b              | 9         | movie_of_a_and_b_and_b1 |
| current_user | b              | 10        | movie_of_b2_first       |
| current_user | b              | 11        | movie_of_b2_second      |
| current_user | c              | 12        | movie_of_c              |
| current_user | d              | 13        | movie_of_d_and_e        |
| current_user | e              | 13        | movie_of_d_and_e        |
+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

I'd like to `GROUP BY COUNT(sugg) AS category_count` to extract this:

```
+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
| user.name    | category_count | ID(movie) | movie.name              |
+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
| current_user | 3              | 14        | movie_c_and_d_and_e     |
| current_user | 2              | 9         | movie_of_a_and_b_and_b1 |
| current_user | 2              | 13        | movie_of_d_and_e        |
| current_user | 1              | 10        | movie_of_b2_first       |
| current_user | 1              | 11        | movie_of_b2_second      |
| current_user | 1              | 12        | movie_of_c              |
+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

How can I accomplish this?

Similar questions:
- [how to have two aggregation in cypher query in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781934/how-to-have-two-aggregation-in-cypher-query-in-neo4j)

**Update**
Here's the working result (with demo: http://tinyurl.com/cywlycc):

```
START movie = node(*)
MATCH user-[:LIKE]->category-[:SIMILAR*0..3]-()<-[:TAGGED]->movie
WHERE user.name = "current_user"
WITH DISTINCT movie, category WITH COUNT(movie) AS category_count, movie, collect(category.name) as categorized
RETURN category_count, ID(movie), movie.name, categorized
ORDER BY category_count DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
START movie = node(*) 
MATCH user-[:LIKE]->category-[:SIMILAR*0..3]-()<-[:TAGGED]->movie 
WHERE user.name = "current_user" 
WITH DISTINCT movie, user, category 
RETURN user.name, count(category.name) as category_count, ID(movie), movie.name 
ORDER BY category_count desc, movie.name asc
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/69rfkn

Comment: Your solution works and answer my question, my query was a bit more complicate than what I presented.. I discovered it is possible to place consequential WITH statements like the following:  START movie = node(*) MATCH user-[:LIKE]->category-[:SIMILAR*0..3]-()<-[:TAGGED]->movie WHERE user.name = "current_user" WITH DISTINCT movie, category WITH COUNT(movie) AS category_count, movie, collect(category.name) as categorized RETURN category_count, ID(movie), movie.name, categorized
ORDER BY category_count DESC; So I can effectly 're-filter' my results. Thank you! http://tinyurl.com/cywlycc

Comment: yes that is what with is for, and you can also apply order and limit per with and aggregate and then filter on the aggregates later on. Perhaps put the updated query in your question so it is better formatted and readable.